# How can I inverse EXPOSE a port to a container?

Tags: docker, networking, port

I am new to Docker and I may not be looking into the right place in the documentation because I couldn't find a way to do what I call "inverse EXPOSE".

So for example, I have one web application that `EXPOSE 80`. That same application is using a postgresql database. When I am locally developing it works fine because I connect to `localhost:5432` but when I containerize the app, it says something like "connection refused". I think the Docker philosophy is to containerize as much as possible and make those containers communicate between each other through a docker network. But I am curious if it actually is possible to say that `localhost:5432` in my container actually refers to the port 5432 on the actual machine that hosts my container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localhost inside a container is not your docker host, it's a namespaced network inside the container. So if you try to communicate with localhost or 127.0.0.1 inside a container, it's only going to communicate with other apps running inside that container.

Instead, you should use the routeable IP of the host, so that requests can come out of the container and back into the docker host interface to reach applications running outside of a container.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that, but what if the docker host has no public ip ?

Comment: You don't need a public ip for the docker host. Just use the ip of the docker host (`docker-machine ip`)

Comment: Is docker setting an environment variable so I can dynamically get the value of the host ip inside my container. If I write the ip inside my code and move my container to another machine it could point to a dead location.

Comment: Docker won't inject an environment variable like this (that could be used as an information leak and potential security exploit vector). You'd need to specify the environment variable yourself.

Comment: @BMitch thanks that was very useful information, I managed to persist this information inside my container and succeeded to connect to my docker host's postgresql process.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is running in the container you should use the `IP:5432` e.g. `192.168.99.100:5432`  of the host and not `localhost`.

When using `localhost` in the container it refers to `localhost (127.0.0.1)` of the container and not the one of the host.